# SQL Merging Two Tables Based on Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Two Views which results will be fetched as shown below

```
select * from CMDowntimes
select * from PMDowntimes
```

The Results of both views is shown in image.all columns names are same except the last column
for q result ser the last column name is "CMDownTime" and for another "PMDowntime"

Now i want to merge these two tables as shown in image
i.e if same id present in both views then ther should be single row in result with both columns "PM_Downtime" and "CM_DownTime" 
if Data is from single Table[view] then the Other one shud be zero(if only CM_Downtime present then PM_Downtime should be Zer0)

waiting for quick responce
Thanx in advance

```
ID Rgn  Ter   StartDate                  EndDate                    CreatedDate  CM_Downtime
13  8   14    2014-10-24 00:30:00.000    2014-10-31 01:00:00.000    2014-10-15   10110
14  6   7     2014-10-01 09:39:00.000    2014-10-03 00:30:00.000    2014-10-26   2331
15  8   14    2014-10-01 09:54:00.000    2014-10-29 09:54:00.000    2014-10-26   40320

ID Rgn  Ter   StartDate                  EndDate                    CreatedDate  PM_Downtime
14  6   7     2014-10-01 09:39:00.000    2014-10-03 00:30:00.000    2014-10-26   2331
16  8   14    2014-10-17 09:57:00.000    2014-10-24 09:57:00.000    2014-10-26   10080


ID Rgn  Ter   StartDate                  EndDate                    CreatedDate  CM_Downtime   PM_Downtime
13  8   14    2014-10-24 00:30:00.000    2014-10-31 01:00:00.000    2014-10-15   10110         0
14  6   7     2014-10-01 09:39:00.000    2014-10-03 00:30:00.000    2014-10-26   2331          2331
15  8   14    2014-10-01 09:54:00.000    2014-10-29 09:54:00.000    2014-10-26   40320         0
16  8   14    2014-10-17 09:57:00.000    2014-10-24 09:57:00.000    2014-10-26   0             10080
```

Comment: Do you use MySQL or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a `full outer join`.  You can do this in either SQL Server or MySQL using `union all` with aggregation:

```
select id, rgn, terr, StartDate, EndDate, CreatedDate,
       max(CM_DownTime) as CM_DownTime, max(PM_DownTime) as PM_DownTime
from (select ID, Rgn, Ter, StartDate, EndDate, CreatedDate, CM_Downtime, 0 as PM_DownTime
      from CMDowntimes
      union all
      select ID, Rgn, Ter, StartDate, EndDate, CreatedDate, 0 as CM_Downtime, PM_DownTime
      from PMDownTimes
     ) dt
group by id, rgn, terr, StartDate, EndDate, CreatedDate;
```

SQL Server supports `full outer join`.  In that database, this probably does what you want:

```
select coalesce(c.id, p.id) as id, coalesce(c.rgn, p.rgn) as rgn, coalesce(c.terr, p.terr) as terr,
       coalesce(c.StartDate, p.StartDate) as StartDate, coalesce(c.EndDate, p.EndDate) as EndDate,
       coalesce(c.CreatedDate, p.CreatedDate) as CreatedDate,
       coalesce(c.CM_Downtime, 0) as CM_Downtime,
       coalesce(p.PM_Downtime, 0) as PM_Downtime
from CMDownTimes c full outer join
     PMDownTimes p
     on c.id = p.id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon.
i was tried with left and outer join..
This is was exactly what i was wanted..
Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    A.ID,
          A.Rgn,
          A.StartDate,
          A.EndDate,
          A.CreatedDate,
          IsNull(A.CM_Downtime, 0),
          IsNull(B.PM_Downtime, 0)
FROM      Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON a.ID = B.ID
UNION
SELECT    A.ID,
          A.Rgn,
          A.StartDate,
          A.EndDate,
          A.CreatedDate,
          IsNull(B.CM_Downtime, 0),
          IsNull(A.PM_Downtime, 0)
FROM      Table2 A
LEFT JOIN Table1 B ON a.ID = B.ID
```